# React - Div of notification banner cut off

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have created a notification component in React from scratch and it is working properly as it should if I use it alone in a new React App.
[image: Notification banner the way it should look like]

My component has the following structure:

```
import React from "react";
import successIcon from "../../../assets/images/check.svg";
import warningIcon from "../../../assets/images/warning.svg";
import errorIcon from "../../../assets/images/error.svg";
import infoIcon from "../../../assets/images/info.svg";
import "./Notification.css";

const Notification = props => {
    let notificationProperties = {};
    const {message} = props;

    if (Object.keys(message).length > 0) {
        switch (props.message.type) {
            case 'success':
                notificationProperties = {
                    title: 'Erfolg',
                    text: props.message.text,
                    backgroundColor: '#5cb85c',
                    icon: successIcon
                };
                break;
            case 'error':
                notificationProperties = {
                    title: 'Fehler',
                    text: props.message.text,
                    backgroundColor: '#d9534f',
                    icon: errorIcon
                };
                break;
            case 'warning':
                notificationProperties = {
                    title: 'Warnung',
                    text: props.message.text,
                    backgroundColor: '#f0ad4e',
                    icon: warningIcon

                };
                break;
            case 'info':
                notificationProperties = {
                    title: 'Info',
                    text: props.message.text,
                    backgroundColor: '#5bc0de',
                    icon: infoIcon
                };
                break;
            default:
              break;
        }

        return (
            <>
                <div className="own-notification-container own-top-right">
                    <div
                        className="own-notification own-toast own-top-right"
                        style={{backgroundColor: notificationProperties.backgroundColor}}>
                        <div className="own-notification-image">
                            <img src={notificationProperties.icon} alt=""/>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <p className="own-notification-title">
                                {notificationProperties.title}
                            </p>
                            <p className="own-notification-message">
                                {notificationProperties.text}
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </>

        )
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

export default Notification;
```

And is using the following css properties:

```
.own-notification-container {
    font-size: 14px;
    z-index: 999999;
    position: fixed;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.own-top-right {
    top: 12px;
    right: 12px;
    transition: transform .6s ease-in-out;
    animation: toast-in-right .7s;
}

.own-bottom-right {
    bottom: 12px;
    right: 12px;
    transition: transform .6s ease-in-out;
    animation: toast-in-right .7s;
}

.own-top-left {
    top: 12px;
    left: 12px;
    transition: transform .6s ease-in;
    animation: toast-in-left .7s;
}

.own-bottom-left {
    bottom: 12px;
    left: 12px;
    transition: transform .6s ease-in;
    animation: toast-in-left .7s;
}

.own-notification {
    transition: .3s ease;
    position: relative;
    pointer-events: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 30px;
    margin: 0 0 15px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #999;
    color: #000;
    opacity: .9;
    background: #fff no-repeat 15px;
}

.own-notification:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 12px #fff;
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: pointer
}

.own-notification-title {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 18px;
}

.own-notification-message {
    text-align: left;
    height: 18px;
    margin: 0 0 0 -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.own-notification-image {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.own-notification-image img {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}

.own-toast {
    height: 50px;
    width: 365px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px 15px 10px 10px;
}

@keyframes toast-in-right {
    from {
        transform: translateX(100%);

    }
    to {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

@keyframes toast-in-left {
    from {
        transform: translateX(-100%);

    }
    to {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}
```

After inserting this component into my complete app I have the following glitch:
[image: Message of the notification is not visible]

The message of the notification is cut off and I don´t have a clue why. The App.js is rendering a **main** html tag with **props.children** and my Notification component.
Any hints why the notification title is not shown?
Note: The searchbar you see in the screenshot isn´t responsible for that glitch. I´ve already switched that component off.

Comment: Where can we see this, so that we can test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´ve solved the problem because I was using two different stylesheets on root level which was responsible for the issue.